# Regarding Set Variable Informatica Power center

Tags: informatica

Regarding Set variable guys. We are using the set variable function. in which aggregation type we set it as Max. So its saving the max value in repository.

So what if we want the repository to save the current value.

Will it work if we set the variable data type as string, so that it wont have aggregation type at all?

Thanks,
Teja

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said the value stored in repository depends on '**Aggregation**'. If it is **Max** then the maximum value is considered and if it is **Min** then the minimum value is considered

Example :
initial value of $$VAR1 = 10

SETVARIABLE($$VAR1, MYVAR)

MYVAR from source = 20

First run: Value 20 is assigned to $$VAR1 and at the end of session 20 is stored in repository for **Aggregation = "MAX"** because 20 is greater than previous repository value i.e., 10

MYVAR from source = 05

Second run : Value 05 is assigned to $$VAR1 and at the end of the session the repository retains 20 because 20 is greater than 5

Now if you want to store the current value try the following steps

1) create a workflow variable $$WFVAR1

2) create an assignment task and initialize the workflow variable

$$WFVAR1 = ''

3) Then in the pre-session variable assignment of your session, assign this workflow variable to your mapping variable (With this your mapping variable gets initialized before your session actually starts)

Hence there is no need to worry about the Aggregation parameter, Always your current value will be stored in the repository

Hope this helps

Thanks and Regards

Raj

Comment: Really appreciate your  clear way of explanation. But if I consider a string and no aggregation type at all how does it work?

Comment: 1) When ever you try to create a mapping variable,  always the Aggregation parameter will be either 'MAX' or 'MIN' (irrespective of the type of variable .. string, date, decimal and so on ). I mean to say there will be a value for aggregation you cannot eliminate it. Only way you can eliminate the aggregation parameter is  to define a mapping parameter instead of variable but 'setvariable' does not work on mapping parameter

Hope this helps

Regards,
Raj

Comment: No I just checked, if the change the data type to string. Aggregation type column is getting deactivated automatically :)

Answer (score 0):

What is the version of informatica you are using? I checked it on 9.1. Find the attached images. When i choose a mapping variable the aggregation is showing either MIN or MAX, but when i choose Mapping Parameter, then only the aggregation is getting disabled

Regards
Raj
[image]

Comment: Hi  I am using 9.6 version.